# How to combine two lines of array and object selection into one?

Tags: php

I have two lines of code that are like this:

```
$arr1 = $obj1->$arr2[$obj2->prop1];

echo $arr1[0]->prop2;
```

I'd like to have them on one line, like this:

```
$arr1 = ($obj1->$arr2[$obj2->prop1])[0]->prop2;
```

But PHP throws an error when I try doing that

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in ...
```

Is it possible to combine those two lines into one somehow? I also tried using braces and square brackets around the first part instead of parenthesis, but no joy.

Comment: Are you sure there is `$` before `arr2`?

Comment: @xdazz - Yes, the value in `$arr2[$obj2->prop1]` is a string with the name of the object being accessed.

Comment: So you need to wrap it with `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code may be written as:

```
$arr1 = $obj1->{$arr2[$obj2->prop1]}[0]->prop2;
```

-I'm treating `$arr2` as some variable that you want to apply for de-ref your object.